# Able to add the same user multiple times to the another model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model which adds(assigns) users to the academy (academy user), the issue is I am able to add the same user multiple times to the academy. What am I doing wrong here?

```
class AcademyPlayer(models.Model):
    academy = models.ForeignKey(Academy, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player = models.ForeignKey('player.Player', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.player.user.name
```

I am adding the `player.Player model` for reference:

```
class Player(models.Model):

    count = models.IntegerField(
        _('count'),
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='player_user')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class AcademyPlayer(models.Model):
    academy = models.OneToOneField(Academy, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player = models.OneToOneField('player.Player', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.player.user.name
```

use `OneToOneField` for this

and dont forget to `makemigrations` and `migrate` after this change

Comment: Thanks for your quick response :)